# Can't find files endswith .sha1 in directory using Python

Tags: python, string, parsing, sha1

my code is reading all the files in directory and subdirectories. I have to count md5, .jar.sha1, etc files. md5 counts fine, but sha1 seems to not count. Tried:

```
1. if file.endswith(".jar.sha1"):
       count += 1

2. if ".jar.sha1" in str(file):
       count += 1
```

Directory is now in Windows, but in future going to be in Linux. Any ideas how to read and get the count of the file string with .sha1 extension?

Thanks

EDIT

The code I have so far:

```
for path in paths_string:
    for root, directories, files in os.walk(path):
        for fil in files:
            f = os.path.join(self.root_dirs(path,root), fil)
            print(f)

            if fil.endswith(".md5"):
                md5_counter += 1
            if fil.endswith(".jar.sha1"):
                sha1_counter += 1       # <- here I had md5_counter += 1
            if fil.endswith(".lastUpdated"):
                lastUpdated_counter += 1
```

Everything works fine.

Comment: Needs more context to how it's used. If `file` is the filename string then option 1 should work fine. If it doesn't, your `file` is probably something different.

Comment: Can you post few more lines of your code. I would like to see how are you getting the data from the dirs and how are you looping through them.

Comment: @xxbinxx see the edit above

Comment: @PeterKovary see the edit. I've changed the `file` I used to `fil` and it can't be detected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to work in both cases for me:

```
>>> file = "myfile.jar.sha1"
>>> file.endswith(".jar.sha1")
True
>>> ".jar.sha1" in str(file)
True
```

Have you tried using the `Path` class?

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> for file in Path("mypath").glob("*jar.sha1"):
...     dosomething()
```

Comment: so apparently I was adding sha1 files count to md5 counter. I guess 12 hrs of coding does make you to do stupid mistakes. Sorry for wasting time.